# How to refresh reading pane content in Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-redemption

We use redemption tools to populate stub-mails with real content. After calling `RDOMail.Import(...)` on the selected item, we close and reopen the preview (*reading*) pane in outlook using

```cs
m_Explorer.ShowPane(MSOutlook.OlPane.olPreview, false);
m_Explorer.ShowPane(MSOutlook.OlPane.olPreview, true);
```

This method works well in Outlook 2007.

But in Outlook 2010 programmatical refresh attempts (*Close/Open Reading pane, Deselect/Select the updated item*) do not work at all. Outlook 2010 still shows the old version.

Does anyone have a hint or a possible solution?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we solved it!

The solution is to

1) Remove the item to update `context.RemoveItem(TargetData.EntryID);` (We are using some abstractions over RDOMessage, MailItem, RDOFolder and MAPIFolder. But I think, the principle behind is quiet clear.

2) Add the new item (`WithComCleanup` is from [VSTOContrib](http://vstocontrib.codeplex.com/) project)

```cs
using (var msg = RDOSession.Resource.GetMessageFromMsgFile(pathToMSG)
                                                     .WithComCleanup())
{ 
     msg.Resource.Move(context.RDOFolder);
     msg.Resource.Save();
}
```

3) Attach an *ItemAdd* handler to *RDOFolder* or *MAPIFolder*, note that the items collection **has to be declared on class level**!
Why ItemAdd? Because neither `RDOMail.OnModified` nor `RDOMail.OnMoved` provided a valid EntryID required for MailItem retrieval. We write custom UserAttributes on fetching, and read them in `ItemAdd`...

```cs
 //...
 m_OwnItems = m_Folder.Items
 m_OwnItems.ItemAdd += new MSOutlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Items_ItemAdd);
 //...

 void Items_ItemAdd(object Item)
 {
     //Outlook 2010: Version 14, only Outlook 2010 supports `ClearSelection` and `AddToSelection`
     if (Item is MSOutlook.MailItem && ApplicationController.Instance.ApplicationVersion.Major >= 14)
     {
         var mail = Item as MSOutlook.MailItem;

         //Check that the added item is the one you added with GetMessageFromMsgFile
         //...

         if (m_Explorer.IsItemSelectableInView(mail))
         {
             m_Explorer.ClearSelection();
             m_Explorer.AddToSelection(mail);
         }
     }    
 }
```

4) It's done! This behavior of Outlook 2010 annoyed us for the whole development time...

Answer (score 3):

Did you try just calling Close on the MailItem?  This refreshes content if the item is selected for me.  Seems an easier solution to what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep in mind that RDOMail.Move returns the new object (just like OOM).
2. Since you are recreating the message, its creation time will change.